# How does this name resolution work with an implementator function and a fallback function?

Tags: c++, metaprogramming

A project I'm working on requires multiple targets to be compiled for. Per target the underlying implementation may vary as the device requires hardware to be configured differently.

In order to force target implementations to follow a interface/design contract system was designed. If a target does not implement said interface accordingly, an error will be thrown upon usage.

The following code is tested using gcc, arm-none-eabi-gcc and clang

```
namespace A {
    namespace C {
        void foo() {}
    }
}

namespace B {
    using namespace A::C;
    void foo() {}
}

using namespace A;
namespace C {

}

int main() {
    B::foo(); // ok
    C::foo(); // won't compile
    return 0;
}
```

Now there are multiple questions that arise when reasoning why this code would compile or not:

Why does the compiler not report unresolved ambiguity between A::foo(bool) and B::set(bool)?

Why does C::foo() **not** compile, since my theory is that the same naming structure is achieved but on a different manner:

Comment: Can you minimize the question? It is wall of (most likely irrelevant) text is it stands right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Why does the compiler not report unresolved ambiguity between target::set(bool) and interface_contracts::set(bool)?

In the first code snippet, name `hwstl::target::pin::set` hides name `hwstl::interface_contracts::pin::set`.

For the call `hwstl::device::pin::set(true);`, name lookup stops upon finding `hwstl::target::pin::set`. Only one candidate function, no ambiguity.

For the call `hwstl::unsatisfied_device::pin::set(true);`, there is only one function called `set` which can be found anyway.

> 10.3.4.1 A using-directive does not add any members to the declarative region in which it appears.

### Why does the following code not compile?

In the second code snippet, you call `set` by qualified id: `hwstl::unsatisfied_device::pin::set`, compiler will only try to find name inside namespace `hwstl::unsatisfied_device::pin`. Thus it failed in finding the name introduced by the using directive `using namespace interface_contracts;` outside it.

Here is a simplified version of your code:

```
namespace A {
    void foo() {}
}

namespace B {
    using namespace A;
    void foo() {}
}

using namespace A;
namespace C {

}

int main() {
    B::foo(); // ok
    C::foo(); // won't compile
    return 0;
}
```